# Disabled button is hidden when disabled

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, overflow

I'm dealing with an issue that shows up for people using Chrome 60.0.3112.90 where changing the `disabled` attribute of a button, hides it.

I've created a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example where you can click the `+` button to toggle the `disabled`  attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/1wtj8a8a/3/

- The element is still present in the DOM
- The element doesn't have `display: none` set
- If you zoom out and zoom in again (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scroll) it shows again
- If you add a margin or padding attribute to the wrap div, it appears again

Removing the `overflow: hidden` seems to solve the problem, but I'd rather not do it, because the text on the buttons will overlap (in my real setup). I've tried replacing it with `overflow-x: hidden`, but to no avail.

#### Question

- Why does this happen?
- What can I do instead of removing `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Removing float helps, too.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're applying `overflow:hidden` directly to your `<button>`... but removing that fixed the problem in my testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, but I've run across randomly disappearing elements before (usually along with `position: fixed`) and using `translateZ(0)` on the element will cause the browser to repaint it, making sure it doesn't disappear.

```js
angular.module('App',[])
 .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.b = true;
    }
])
```

```css
div.wrap {
  width: 50px;
}
button {
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
  <div class="wrap">
    <button class="btn btn-mini pull-left">A</button>
    <button class="btn btn-mini pull-right" ng-disabled="b">B</button> 
  </div>
  <button ng-click="b=!b">+</button>
</div>
</body>
```